# Twilio Sync - identity is required to be specified in options

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, ngrok, twilio-click-to-call

Hi everyone Im using twilio voice javascript sdk with ngrok that i found their repository in GitHub
the installation went good when i try to click on start up the device to get the client name from my name generator js an error has showed and i can not get the client client name or make any calls

i have set up my index js with all my **account sid** and **phone number** and **twiml app sid** and  **Twilio api secret key**

**cmd error**

```
Error: identity is required to be specified in options
    at new AccessToken (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\twilio\lib\jwt\AccessToken.js:202:19)
    at tokenGenerator (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\src\handler.js:13:23)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\src\router.js:7:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    at C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)       
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\voice-javascript-sdk-quickstart-node\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
```

**ngrok error when i click on start up the device**

```
HTTP Requests
-------------

GET /quickstart.js             200 OK
GET /twilio.min.js             200 OK
GET /site.css                  200 OK
GET /                          200 OK
GET /                          502 Bad Gateway
```

**config.js**

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cfg = {};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "test") {
  dotenv.config({ path: ".env" });
} else {
  dotenv.config({ path: ".env.example", silent: true });
}

// HTTP Port to run our web application
cfg.port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Your Twilio account SID and auth token, both found at:
// https://www.twilio.com/user/account
//
// A good practice is to store these string values as system environment
// variables, and load them from there as we are doing below. Alternately,
// you could hard code these values here as strings.
cfg.accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;

cfg.twimlAppSid = process.env.TWILIO_TWIML_APP_SID;
cfg.callerId = process.env.TWILIO_CALLER_ID;

cfg.apiKey = process.env.TWILIO_API_KEY;
cfg.apiSecret = process.env.TWILIO_API_SECRET;

// Export configuration object
module.exports = cfg;
```

Comment: Why did you use the php tag for this question? Also, where do you access the `config.js` file?

Comment: sorry for the php tag it was a mistake and i access the config.js file i have an .env file that contains all my account sid and api key secret and phone number etc...

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(cfg)` to check if it contains the right values?

Comment: How i can do that ?? i`m no quiet familiar with this brother

Comment: I added the code as an answer

Comment: Can you add the code/file in which you'll access the Twilio client?

Comment: okay i will do that is it the .env file ?

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, I just ran in a similar issue and wanted to leave a hint here.

With version 4 of the Node.js client [`twilio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio), you now need to supply a `identity` property in the config.

```js
const token = new AccessToken(
  TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  TWILIO_API_KEY,
  TWILIO_API_SECRET,
  { identity },
);
```

If this is missing, you get the error you mentioned above. You can fix it by adding the identify or by downgrading the twilio dependency if you can't edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried logging the `cfg` object to see whether it contains all the expected values?

You can do this when you end the `config.js` file as follows:

```js
console.log(cfg);

// Export configuration object
module.exports = cfg;
```

Comment: i`ve tried that and it shows me in console all my correct values such as port number / twilio account sid/ twiml app sid /caller id/api key/ api secret. and when i click on start up the device the same error show Error: identity is required to be specified in options